# JavaFX valueAt() Binding only compute once

Tags: java, kotlin, javafx, binding, listproperty

We know that `ListExpression` has a method [`ObjectBinding<E> valueAt(ObservableIntegerValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/ListExpression.html#valueAt-javafx.beans.value.ObservableIntegerValue-). We can use this method to listen to an element of a `ListProperty` exactly.

I expect it will both bind to the `ListProperty` and the `ObservableNumberValue`. So either the list changes or the observable number value changes will make the binding invalid and recompute. But in the following code, the binding is computed only once! (Actually twice, if we don't ignore the initial computation)

The label will display a random string at the beginning. And the `property` will have 100 Bean as the initial value. If we click `button1`, the `indexProperty` will increase by 1. If we click `button2`, the Bean located at the *current index of the ListProperty* will change. Both effects will make the binding invalid and recompute the label text.

But in practice, the text will change the first time when one button is clicked. And will not change anymore.

I'm using Liberica JDK17 which contains jmods of JavaFX by default.

```kotlin
class FixmeApp : Application() {

    companion object {
        fun genRandomDouble(): Double = Math.random() * 10000
        fun genRandomString(): String = genRandomDouble().roundToInt().toString(36)
    }

    class Bean {
        val stringProperty = SimpleStringProperty(genRandomString())
        val doubleProperty = SimpleDoubleProperty(genRandomDouble())
    }

    val property: ListProperty<Bean> = SimpleListProperty(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Bean()))

    override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {
        property.addAll((0..100).map { Bean() })

        val indexProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(0)

        val label = Label().apply {
            textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
                { genRandomString() },
                property.valueAt(indexProperty)
            ))
        }
        val button1 = Button("Change Index").apply {
            setOnAction {
                indexProperty.set(indexProperty.get() + 1)
            }
        }
        val button2 = Button("Change Bean").apply {
            setOnAction {
                property[indexProperty.get()] = Bean()
            }
        }
        val scene = Scene(BorderPane().apply {
            center = label
            bottom = HBox(button1, button2)
        })

        primaryStage.scene = scene
        primaryStage.show()

    }

}

fun main() {
    Application.launch(FixmeApp::class.java)
}
```

By the way, if we change the binding dependencies from `property.valueAt(indexProperty)` to `property, indexProperty`, the code will run as we expected.

In my program, the binding will return the property of Bean at the location *indexProperty.get()* of *property*

---

### Edit (by James_D):

To increase the audience for this question, here is (to the best of my knowledge) a translation of this example to Java.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Random;

public class FixMeApp extends Application {

    private final Random rng = new Random();

    private final ListProperty<Bean> property = new SimpleListProperty<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++) property.add(new Bean());
        var index = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        var label =  new Label();
        label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
                this::generateRandomString,
                property.valueAt(index)
        ));
        var button1 = new Button("Change Index");
        button1.setOnAction(e -> index.set(index.get() + 1));
        var button2 = new Button("Change bean");
        button2.setOnAction(e -> property.set(index.get(), new Bean()));
        var root = new BorderPane(label);
        root.setBottom(new HBox(button1, button2));
        var scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private double generateRandomDouble() {
        return rng.nextDouble() * 10000 ;
    }

    private String generateRandomString() {
        return Integer.toString((int) generateRandomDouble());
    }

    class Bean {
        private StringProperty stringProperty = new SimpleStringProperty(generateRandomString());
        private DoubleProperty doubleProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(generateRandomDouble());

        StringProperty stringProperty() { return stringProperty; }
        DoubleProperty doubleProperty() { return doubleProperty; }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8273138

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to reply in Java, as I'm more familiar with it. The reasoning applies to kotlin too.

`Bindings.createStringBinding(function, dependencies)` creates a binding that is invalidated any time any of the dependencies are invalidated. Here "invalidated" means "changes from a valid state to an invalid state". The problem with your code is that you define the dependency as `property.valueAt(index)`, which is a binding to which you have no other reference.

When you change either the index or the bean at that index in the list, then the binding becomes invalid. Since you never compute the value of that binding again, *it never becomes valid again* (i.e. it never holds, or has returned, a valid value). So subsequent changes will not change its validation state (it is simply still invalid; it cannot transition from valid to invalid).

Changing the code to

```java
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
        () -> property.valueAt(index).get().stringBinding().get(),
        property.valueAt(index)
));
```

doesn't help: you have one binding used for the dependency (whose value is never computed, so it is never returned to a valid state) and a different binding each time the value is computed. The value of the binding used as the dependency is never computed, so it is never returned to a valid state, and consequently can never become invalidated again.

However

```java
ObjectBinding<Bean> bean = property.valueAt(index);
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
        () -> bean.get().stringProperty().get(),
        bean
));
```

will work. Here the computation of the text forces `bean` to compute its current value, returning it to a valid state. Then subsequent changes to the index or the list will invalidate `bean` again, triggering recomputation of the binding to which `text` is bound.

I think the kotlin translation of this is

```kotlin
val bean = property.valueAt(indexProperty)
val label = Label().apply {
    textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
        { bean.value.stringProperty.value },
        bean
    ))
}
```

You can experiment with other variations. This one doesn't update more than once, because `bean` is never validated:

```java
ObjectBinding<Bean> bean = property.valueAt(index);
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
        this::generateRandomString,
        bean
));
```

Whereas this one forces validation, so it always updates:

```java
ObjectBinding<Bean> bean = property.valueAt(index);
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
        () -> {
            bean.get();
            return generateRandomString();
        },
        bean
));
```

Comment: If anyone can fix the syntax highlighting here, please feel free...

Comment: That's totally correct @James_D.  The Properties inside of Properties indexed by a Property through valueAt() gets pretty wild.  The key point here being that you need to have a get() in the value calculation for every Observable used as a trigger for the Binding.  The Kotlin's not bad, but you should use "value" instead of "get" (or even get()).

Comment: @DaveB Thanks for the Kotlin hint; that makes sense. I edited that code block.

Comment: @DaveB I would be careful with using `property.value` when the property wraps a primitive type, because that syntax will lead to the `property.getValue()` method being called which is defined to return the boxed type. I doubt doing otherwise will lead to a significant performance hit in most circumstances, but using `.get()` makes sure the primitive type is not boxed (at least at that point in the code).

Comment: @Slaw  I agree.  Personally, I hate dealing with Number, so I've started using ObjectProperty<Int> or ObjectProperty<Double>, instead of IntegerProperty or DoubleProperty.  I think that this tends to make the getValue() v. get() issue mostly moot.  I need to take a peek at the source for TornadoFX to see how they deal with this kind of stuff.

Comment: For future readers, check out: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8273138

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @James_D, I not only know why this code did not run as expected but also solved another issue related to Bindings.

TL;DR - **JavaFX won't automatically validate bindings when the dependencies become invalid**. You should validate them by getting the value or somehow.

In the following code, `bean` will become invalid either `property` or `index` changes, and the `StringBinding` will compute. After the computation, **bean is still invalid** because we didn't compute to validate it. So next time the dependencies of `bean` change, the `StringBinding` will not recompute.

```
ObjectBinding<Bean> bean = property.valueAt(index);
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
        this::generateRandomString,
        bean
));
```

But for this one, it is different. Though we never use the binding `bean`'s value, we validate it by getting. So the code runs as expected.

```
ObjectBinding<Bean> bean = property.valueAt(index);
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
        () -> {
            bean.get();
            return generateRandomString();
        },
        bean
));
```

And for another situation, be careful! May `bean` became invalid and during the computation, the `flag` was `false` so `bean` **didn't validate**. If we don't validate `bean` somehow somewhere before next time `bean`'s dependencies become invalid again, **the binding will not compute**.

```
ObjectBinding<Bean> bean = property.valueAt(index);
label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(
        () -> {
            if (flag) return bean.value 
            else return generateRandomString();
        },
        bean
));
```

Comment: I'm curious, because you don't seem to use the Properties in Bean as Properties.  Also, using a Binding when you aren't going to use any of the bound trigger properties seems to be a bit of a code smell.  Wouldn't it be more obvious/direct to just use an InvalidationListener here instead?

Comment: Aha, InvalidationListener! I even didn't notice it. Thank you for the advice. :)